# Add build config values to manifest metadata

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-gradle-plugin, android-maps-v2

I have some google map api keys for my app (debug and release).

In order to use the API i have to add the key in the manifest like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.API_KEY"
        android:value="apikey" />
```

For security reasons I don't want to leave the raw key in the manifest.

What is the best work around for this or the recommended way to do this?

I currently have to variables in my build config which have keys for debug and release.

Comment: Store your KEY in String and load it

Comment: @MD how safe is that though, to directly store it in the string?

Answer (score 2):

Do the keys in 'gradle.build' for the 'app'.

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        buildConfigField "String", "DBREST", "\"DB REST RELEASE\""
        resValue "string", "maps_api_key", configMapApiR

    }
    debug {

        buildConfigField "String", "DBREST", "\"DB REST RELEASE\""
        resValue "string", "maps_api_key", configMapApiD

    }
}
```

insert the key values in the 'gradle.properties' as std K-V pairs

```
configMapApiR=$yourKey
configMapApiD=
```

Use the android resource value in code...

```
  getString(R.string.maps_api_key));
```